# Why did my new anwer not bump up the Squirrel question to the top of the question list?

Tags: discussion

**I'm not complaining, I'm just curious.**

I wrote an answer to the question about [humanely killing a squirrel](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19622/how-do-i-kill-a-squirrel-humanely/19632#19632) and was surprised to see that my answer had not bumped the question to the top of the question list.

Was it because the Q had been highly downvoted (minus five) or because an answer (downvoted to minus two) had been accepted already, or a combination of the two?  Is there some combination of downvotes that makes a question so not-interesting that a new answer cannot push it to the top of the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the question has so many downvotes, it is removed from the front page. I think (but I can't confirm right now) that a score of -3 will do this. The reason being that it is a question considered not suitable for the site, and unfortunately even an excellent answer will not change this.

The best fix is, if possible, to help improve the question to see if it can gain upvotes.